# How to get only First Name Last Name from LDAP CN when format is last name\, first name

Tags: java, regex

CN=Belzile\, Pierre,OU=LaptopUser,OU=Users,DC=Company,DC=local

I need only "Belzile Pierre" to be returned.
I need help with the regex syntax

For the regular expression we use Java syntax https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

Expected Result:
Belzile Pierre

Comment: What output do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex and capture firstname and last name in group1 and group2,

```
CN=([a-zA-Z]+)\\,\s+([a-zA-Z]+)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jHr2l2/1)**

Java code,

```
String s = "CN=Belzile\\, Pierre,OU=LaptopUser,OU=Users,DC=Company,DC=local";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("CN=([a-zA-Z]+)\\\\,\\s+([a-zA-Z]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2));
}
```

Prints your expected output,

```
Belzile Pierre
```

Comment: Don't mind the downvote but If something doesn't seem correct, help me learn something good too and I will happily improve my answer.

Comment: It was very close.  The output I am getting now is Belzile-Pierre   How to remove the dash?

Comment: Works now!  I fund a parameter that was adding the dash.  Thanks so much!